# Start thinking sphinx on Ubuntu startup

Tags: 12.04, server, rails

I need run this rails command automatically, from my project folder, every time my server starts up:

```
rake ts:start
```

I put a file called `run_ts.sh` in my rails project folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
rake ts:start
```

In `/etc/rc.local` I added:

```
/usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/eximquota
/usr/local/ispmgr/sbin/ihttpd iphidden
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
/home/prog/OnlineAuto/Shop/run_ts.sh
exit 0
```

But my command is not executing, so `rake ts:start` is not executed.

How can I start thinking sphinx on each system startup?

Comment: If you launch it manually with `/home/prog/OnlineAuto/Shop/run_ts.sh` does it work?

Comment: @dadexix86 yes it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system startup scripts won't be started from your project directory, so you need to switch to it explicitly in your script.

`run_ts.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/prog/OnlineAuto/Shop
rake ts:start
```

If this needs to be run with a specific user account rather than root, try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
su - username -c 'cd /home/prog/OnlineAuto/Shop ; rake ts:start'
```

Comment: hm, still not working

Comment: Should that script be run by a specific user perhaps? What user would that be?

Comment: hm, didn't know, i want to start this script by default, without any users... But! let's try with user prog... what to change?

Comment: yes, really with user is ok!

Comment: where i need to write it? i forget )